# Unexpected behavior with implicits

Tags: scala, implicit

I had a strange bug yesterday that I eventually reduced to the following code:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_29).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class X extends Function[String, Int] { def apply(x: String) = Integer.parseInt(x) }
defined class X

scala> implicit val x = new X
x: X = <function1>

scala> "56" / 2
res2: Int = 28
```

I expect this to throw an exception, since String doesn't have a `/` method. Instead, Scala treated the implicit variable as an implicit method (because it implements `Function[String,Int]`) and converted  the string "56" to the integer 56.

How does this work? Based on the rules of implicit search, I didn't think implicit variables that act as functions would be considered.

Comment: Actually, an `implicit def` conversion works because it is automatically transformed into a function value (that's _eta expansion_).

Answer (score 7):

The semantics of implicit conversions are exactly what you've observed. If you define an implicit conversion via an implicit method,

```
trait A
trait B

implicit def aToB(a : A) : B = new B {}
```

you'll see that you now have an implicit function value `A => B`,

```
scala> implicitly[A => B]
res1: A => B = <function1>
```

And where you have a method with a view bound,

```
def foo[T <% B](t : T) : B = t
```

this is equivalent to,

```
def foo[T](t : T)(implicit conv : T => B) : B = conv(t)
```

ie. the implicit argument corresponding to a view bound is of exactly the same form as the implicit function value produced by an implicit method definition.

Comment: So are implicit methods reduced to implicit variables of Function type? Or Scala just handles both cases?

Comment: In any context in which the method must be reified as a function value (that includes applications involving view bounds), yes. In my example, if you just did (new A {} : B) the method would be applied without actually creating a function object first, but the mechanism is identical, hence the behaviour you observed.